# Jquery datatable and download xls

Tags: jquery, datatables, xlsx

I have one **jQuery data table** and one button, my requirement is if i am clicking the button means i have to download xls format in table values,I tried but i am not able to do, i am person of development please any one update my code, i tried and i searched still i am not getting the code please any one help me.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Export to Xls</button>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 4.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td> 4</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.5
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5.5</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 6
          </td>
          <td>Win 98+</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
          <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>

        </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
```

Comment: *if i am clicking the button means i have to download xls format in table values* not clear whats your problem

Answer (score 0):

You can use table2excel plugin to do this. see code below.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-header">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="exportToExcel('#example1')">Export to Xls</button>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-header -->
  <div class="box-body">
    <table id="example1" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Rendering engine</th>
          <th>Browser</th>
          <th>Platform(s)</th>
          <th>Engine version</th>
          <th>CSS grade</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 4.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td> 4</td>
          <td>X</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.0
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5</td>
          <td>C</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 5.5
          </td>
          <td>Win 95+</td>
          <td>5.5</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 6
          </td>
          <td>Win 98+</td>
          <td>6</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Trident</td>
          <td>Internet Explorer 7</td>
          <td>Win XP SP2+</td>
          <td>7</td>
          <td>A</td>
        </tr>

        </tfoot>
    </table>
  </div>
  <!-- /.box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.box -->
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/rainabba/jquery-table2excel/1.1.0/dist/jquery.table2excel.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function exportToExcel(table){
        jQuery(table).table2excel({
            name: "report",
            filename: "report" //do not include extension
        }); 
    }
</script>
```